# Error "PageMethods is undefined" in Webpart for Sharepoint 2010

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting PageMethods is not defined javascript error in my sharepoint 2010 webpart.
Basically, i have created webpart which displays the google map. upon clicking the marker of the google map, i want to call the server side event. I have implemented the jquery for the same. I am using the PageMethods to call the server method. Below is the code which i fetched from some blog site only. I have also addeed the scriptmanager tag on my page with the EnablePageMethods attribute set to true.

Script block:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Initialization                            
        $("#ajax_loading_image").hide();
        // mousemove event
        $().mousemove(function (e) {
            window.status = e.pageX + ', ' + e.pageY;
        });
        // hook up the click event            
        $("#execute_page_method").click(function () {

            $("#message").text("I'm working...");
            $("#ajax_loading_image").show("fast");
            $("#execute_page_method").hide("fast");

            // Call some page method...
            PageMethods.ProperMethodName("string", function (result, userContext, methodName) {

                $("#ajax_loading_image").hide("slow");
                $("#execute_page_method").show("slow");

                if (result.Success == true) {
                    alert("true");
                    $("body").css("background", "#CAFFD8");
                }
                else {
                    $("body").css("background", "#CAFFFF");
                }

                $("#message").text("This took me " + result.Time + " milliseconds...  ");

            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<div>
    <a id="execute_page_method" href="http://jquery.com/">Click!</a>
</div>

Code Behind events:
public class MethodReturnedValue
        {
            public int Time { get; set; }
            public bool Success { get; set; }
        }

        [WebMethod(true)]
        public static MethodReturnedValue ProperMethodName(string param)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            MethodReturnedValue retVal = new MethodReturnedValue();
            retVal.Time = random.Next(5000);
            Thread.Sleep(retVal.Time);
            if (random.Next() % 2 == 0)
            {
                retVal.Success = true; ;
            }
            else
            {
                retVal.Success = false;
            }
            return retVal;
        }
```

The same code is works fine in my asp.net appication and not working in my sharepoint application.
Can anyone please help me out in this.

Answer (score 0):

For Page methods, the Web Method needs to be in .aspx.cs file.

In SharePoint (if using publishing page layout), write the web method in page's cs.

But if you are using Web Part Page layout then it won't work.